# How to reinterpret cast an array and is it safe to do so?

Tags: c++

```
// this boxes8a contains a flat array of floats
// There are n boxes and the array is n * 8 long
float* boxes8a = ...;
```

I want to reinterpret this into an array of Box, where each box contains an array of 4 points. And each point contains 2 floats, (x, y)

```
struct Box
{
  point points[4]
}

struct point
{
   float x, y
}
```

Q1: How do I cast the `float* boxes8a` into an array of Box?

Q2: Is it a good practice to do this?

Comment: _"`Q2: is it good practice to do this?"_ Nope!

Comment: Should I just loop through the `float * boxes8a` and copy the value into a `std::vector<Box>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***How do I cast the `float* boxes8a` into an array of `Box`?***

Dangerously.

```
//Undefined Behavior, might not do what you want it to do!
Box* boxes = reinterpret_cast<Box*>(boxes8a);
```

> ***Is it good practice to do this?***

No.

This is considered Undefined Behavior in C++, and while many compilers will give you results that seem like they work if you attempt this, I cannot advise it. Your best solution is to simply copy the values into `Box` objects and let the objects own their own data.

```
std::vector<Box> boxes(n);
for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        boxes[i][j] = point{boxes8a[i*8 + j*2 + 0], boxes8a[i*8 + j*2 + 1]};
}
```

Alternately, and at the risk of sounding like one of the Data-Oriented-Design <strike>Cultists</strike> Proponents, you might consider having the `Box` object simply contain a pointer to a location in the array where its data begins:

```
class point {
    float* data;
public:
    point(float* data) : data(data) {}

    float& x() const {return *data;}
    float& y() const {return *(data+1);}
};

class Box {
    float* data;
public:
    Box(float* data) : data(data) {}

    point operator[](size_t index) const {
        return point(data + index * 2);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Box> boxes;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        boxes.emplace_back(boxes8a + i*8);

    boxes[3][3].x() = 34.7; //Will alter the original value in boxes8a!
}
```

This method will allow the `Box` objects to alias the original `float*` array without breaking aliasing rules.

Answer (score 3):

> Q1: how do I cast the `float* boxes8a` into an array of Box?

This is not something you should solve by casting.  A `float*` and a `Box` are different things.  They both might be built with floats but they are aren't related so can't be cast to each other, as that would be a strict aliasing violation.

> Q2: is it good practice to do this?

No.  As stated above you aren't allowed to do so.

What you can do though is use [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to copy the value of the `float` array into the `Box` array.  That would look like

```
float* boxes8a = some_data;
Box array[correct_size];
static_asset(sizeof(Box) == sizeof(float) * 8, "data sizes are incompatible");
std::memcpy(array, boxes8a, correct_size);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: how do I cast the float* boxes8a into an array of Box?

```
Box* boxes = std::reinterpret_cast<Box*>(boxes8a);
```

> Q2: is it good practice to do this?

No, this is an abomination. <strike>`struct point` can have padding inside or between elements in the array</strike>.  It's undefined behaviour. Please redesign your solution to the problem,

Comment: The padding isn't the problem (and padding can be removed with compiler-specific attributes). The problem is lying to the compiler!